# What is the difference between RegOpenKeyExA and RegOpenKeyEx

Tags: registry, 32bit-64bit

Could find MSDN documentation only on [RegOpenKeyExA](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winreg/nf-winreg-regopenkeyexa).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function `RegOpenKeyExA` is the ANSI version of the `RegOpenKeyEx`, which is a wrapper to the function `RegOpenKeyExW`, the UTF-16 version.

In the context of the functions in question, the ANSI version requires the second parameter (i.e. the name of the registry subkey to be opened) to be of a `LPCSTR` type whereas the UTF-16 version requires the same parameter to be of a `LPCWSTR` type.